# What does flag 0x10000000 represent on WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED message?

Tags: windows, winapi

Windows API documentation and headers files don't include all flags possible for the [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-windowposchanged) and [`WINDOWPOS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-windowpos) structure.

```
// WINDOWPOS documentation
SWP_NOSIZE          0x0001
SWP_NOMOVE          0x0002
SWP_NOZORDER        0x0004
SWP_NOREDRAW        0x0008
SWP_NOACTIVATE      0x0010
SWP_FRAMECHANGED    0x0020 = SWP_DRAWFRAME /* The frame changed: send WM_NCCALCSIZE */
SWP_SHOWWINDOW      0x0040
SWP_HIDEWINDOW      0x0080
SWP_NOCOPYBITS      0x0100
SWP_NOOWNERZORDER   0x0200 = SWP_NOREPOSITION /* Don't do owner Z ordering */
SWP_NOSENDCHANGING  0x0400  /* Don't send WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING */
// From other sources
SWP_NOCLIENTSIZE    0x0800 // Winehq source
SWP_NOCLIENTMOVE    0x1000 // Winehq source
SWP_DEFERERASE      0x2000 // SetWindowPos function documentation
SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS  0x4000 // SetWindowPos function documentation
SWP_STATECHANGED    0x8000 // Winehq source

// ??? unknown
????????????????    0x1000_0000
```

When my program starts it receives `268441667` as flag. That is:

```
0x10001843
    0x0001 SWP_NOSIZE
    0x0002 SWP_NOMOVE
    0x0040 SWP_SHOWWINDOW
    0x0800 SWP_NOCLIENTSIZE /* Client didn't resize */  /* ;Internal */
    0x1000 SWP_NOCLIENTMOVE /* Client didn't move   */  /* ;Internal */
0x10000000 (undocumented)
```

But i don't know what it means so i cant rely on it.

Comment: It's an internal flag. You should just ignore it.